# with urllib urlopen read function but get none

Tags: python, urlopen

[https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=LN594080445CN]

```
import urllib
url='https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=LN594080445CN'  
page=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

but get page=''

my version:2.7.6

Comment: it may be due to ssl, or user agent

Comment: please specify which version of Python you are using and how you import your modules. When I copy your code and `import urllib` it says `urllib` has no method `urlopen` :)

Comment: why are you using urllib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum I try with the python package [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and first have an error :
`requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects`.

It seems it redirects from url to another and loop like that. Maybe it failed with urllib.
Also I checked doc of urlopen and seems to have some problem with https request.

Whatever I found this piece of code which fix your issue :

```
import requests

url='https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=LN594080445CN'

s = requests.session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'

response = s.get(url)
print response.text
```

Creating the session fix the error about the max redirection error. More information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651947/python-requests-requests-exceptions-toomanyredirects-exceeded-30-redirects).
In `response.text` you have all the code page, which what you want I guess.

Of course you need to add YOUR specific user agent. For the example there is mine but yours might be different. You can find it [here](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/)
hope it helps !

Comment: ,i have tried,sometimes another problem will appear,however ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this URL and found the error is due to a HTTP Error 301. It should be caused by the anti-spider mechanism of this website. You have to design a sophisticated user agent to get the page, instead of just a simple `urlopen`.

Comment: ,yep,i have to do sth. more

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not using `urllib` in any modern Python context. Use "[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)" ("HTTP for Humans") instead.

But before that, as @Skyler said, the result is a redirect, and your first stop should be to see what `curl` reports:

```
$ curl -I 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=LN594080445CN\]'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://www.usps.com/root/global/server_responses/webtools-msg.htm
Date: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 10:43:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

No big deal, but you can see that the [URL it redirects to states](https://www.usps.com/root/global/server_responses/webtools-msg.htm):

> To learn about integrating the free Postal Service® Address and
>   Tracking API's into your application, please visit
>   www.usps.com/webtools.

Also fair enough. I suggest going there and signing up. No point scraping HTML when there's a proper way to do it.

BUT, if you *really* want to pull the raw HTML via code: first get it working via Curl.

Pull up the Chrome developer tools and reload the page. Right click and look for "copy as CURL". You can edit the link. The following worked for me though it could probably be trimmed more:

```
curl 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=LN594080445CN\]' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
--compressed
```

This can be trimmed. The code below works with the nice `requests` module:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
}
r = requests.get('https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=LN594080445CN]', headers=headers)

print "Status: %s" % r.status_code
print "Content-type: %s" % r.headers['content-type']
print "Content length: %d" % len(r.text)
```

Running:

```
$ python demo.py
Status: 200
Content-type: text/html
Content length: 55142
```

Even cleaner:

```
params = {
    'tRef': 'fullpage',
    'tLc': '1',
    'text28777': '',
    'tLabels': 'LN594080445CN]',
}

r = requests.get('https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action',
        params=params,
        headers=headers)
```

As I said though, I think this is not the right choice. Use the USPS API.