# Python Exceeded 30 redirects

Tags: python

I have tried the following code but it throws an error :

```
import requests


url = 'https://et.interac.ca/sh/9bk0vt9w'
s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
r = s.get(url)
print(r)
```

ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/prisjakt/scr/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    r = s.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\prisjakt\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\prisjakt\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\prisjakt\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\prisjakt\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\prisjakt\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 166, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded {} redirects.'.format(self.max_redirects), response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

My Goal is to scrape the final URL.

Comment: look here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651947/python-requests-requests-exceptions-toomanyredirects-exceeded-30-redirects

Comment: Yes tried the same code as well

Comment: does the url you use have you tried it with browser, does it give too many redirects error in browser as well

Comment: running in window browser and sending mac user agent data might cause this, better to add window user agent

Comment: @bhucho no it does not give so many redirections in browser

Comment: @sahasrara62 I tried windows user agent as well it still gives error